# Spring SmartLifecycle start() method not executed

Tags: java, spring, threadpoolexecutor

In my spring app I have a thread pool manager that during start() creates some threads and add those to the pool. But while running the start() method is never executed.

```
@Component
public class ThreadPoolManager implements SmartLifecycle {

    private static final Logger logger = 
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThreadPoolkManager.class);

    ScheduledExecutorService httpCheckPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

    @Override
    public void start() {
       /**
        * Start some threads
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        httpCheckPool.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return !httpCheckPool.isTerminated();
    }

    public synchronized void addServiceToCheck(NewService service){
        /**
         * Add service to the threadpool
         */
    }
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Is this question solved ? If yes, please mark it as solved using the dedicated button and explain your solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for someone facing similar problem. `isRunning()` is called before `start()` therefore make sure `isRunning()` returns `false` initially then only `start()` is executed. Simple way to do this is use a flag.